# Localhost constantly reports: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 704384 bytes)

Tags: php, xampp

I've got XAMPP running on my local Windows machine to process some simple text files using PHP. It's a fresh install so there's no history of issues prior.

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 704384 bytes)

I thought the solution would be pretty easy. I've tried increasing the memory size to 256M (not 256MB!), I've also tried the bytes version of it (268435456).
There was only php.ini in the C:\xampp\php folder, there's nothing in the apache\bin regarding php.ini

Also tried setting the memory manually in the script itself using

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

With no luck. The task itself is very basic - reading in a 640KB file.

Any ideas on what I else I can try?

Comment: What are you doing with that text file? I mean either upload it Or process it for something or what

Comment: Sounds like the issue is with the code rather than PHP Configuration. A 640Kb file shouldn't consume such memory - perhaps if you posted that code the problem might become clear

Comment: @TobiasF. Isn't 262144 BYTES = ~256KB? 704384 bytes should be under 1MB

Comment: @Rupal Nothing special to be honest, just a simple strpos to see if the text contains a certain string so it can either be flagged as having the string or not having the string

Comment: @RamRaider It's pretty much just this one line where it breaks -> file_get_contents("data/id_".$id.".txt");

Comment: Whoops, wrong factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

or

```
php.ini  =>  memory_limit = 256M
```

or

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

PHP's config can be set in multiple places:

1. master system php.ini (usually in /etc somewhere)
2. somewhere in Apache's configuration (httpd.conf or a per-site .conf file, via php_value)
3. CLI & CGI can have a different php.ini (use the command php -i | grep memory_limit to check the CLI conf)
4. local .htaccess files (also php_value)

Also note that PHP generally has different .ini files for command-line and webserver-based operation. Checking phpinfo() from the command line will report different values than if you'd run it in a web-based script.

Comment: I've tried the first one, not sure where the second and third one goes? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @allanminium, I updated my answer.I hope it will work for you.

Comment: `Also note that PHP generally has different .ini files for command-line and webserver-based operation. `

This is the line that helped me! I did not know that as I usually run webserver based scripts, but for the first time, I'm running a command line script. I ended up finding this command -

`php -d memory_limit=128M my_script.php`

Source: [link](https://cristian-radulescu.ro/article/php-cli-increase-memory-limit.html)